# Why does Sympy not evaluate the integral and simply displays it?

Tags: python, math, sympy, tensor, integral

I have created a python script that can find christoffel symbols and solve geodesic equations. I thought today that it would be useful to add the feature to calculate arc length in curved 2D space. I have created the code using sympy, and everything seems to be correct, but for some reason it just doesn't evaluate the integral! It simply shows the integral. Can someone please help me. I have tried everything, even using dsolve but nothing works. This is the current state of my code:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.interactive import printing

printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)

g = [[[11], [12]], [[21], [22]]]


l = sp.symbols("l")
k = sp.symbols('k')
t = sp.symbols('t')


u = sp.Function('u')(l)
v = sp.Function('v')(l)



u_func = sp.exp(l)
v_func = sp.sin(l)


basis = [u, v]
funcs = [u_func, v_func]



X, Y, Z = sp.cos(v) * sp.sin(u), sp.sin(v) * sp.sin(u), sp.cos(u)

R = sp.Function('R')(X, Y, Z)
eu = sp.diff(R, u)
ev = sp.diff(R, v)



def compute_inverse_metric_tensor(g=g):
    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):
            g[i][j] = sp.simplify(
                sp.diff(X, basis[i]) * sp.diff(X, basis[j]) + sp.diff(Y, basis[i]) * sp.diff(Y, basis[j]) + sp.diff(Z,
                                                                                                                    basis[
                                                                                                                        i]) * sp.diff(
                    Z, basis[j]))

            if i == j:
                g[i][j] = 1 / g[i][j]
            else:
                g[i][j] = -g[i][j]

    return g


def calculate_arc_length(g=compute_inverse_metric_tensor(),u=u,v=v,X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z,l=l,a=0,b=1):

    magRsqrt = []
    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):
            if i == j:
                g[i][j] = 1 / g[i][j]
            else:
                g[i][j] = -g[i][j]

    print(g)

    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):

            term = sp.diff(funcs[i],l)*sp.diff(funcs[j],l) * g[i][j]
            term = term.subs(u, u_func)
            term = term.subs(v, v_func)
            magRsqrt.append(term)

    magR = (sp.simplify(sp.sqrt(sum(magRsqrt))))
    display(magR)
    arclen = sp.Integral(magR,(l,a,b)).doit()
    arclen.doit()
    display(arclen)
   
    
    


def calculate_Christoffel_Symbols(R=R, u=u, v=v, g=compute_inverse_metric_tensor()):
    G = [[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]], [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]]

    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):
            for k in range(len(basis)):
                for m in range(len(basis)):
                    G[i][j][k][0] += sp.diff(X, basis[i], basis[j]) * sp.diff(X, basis[m]) * g[m][k] + sp.diff(Y,
                                                                                                               basis[i],
                                                                                                               basis[
                                                                                                                   j]) * sp.diff(
                        Y, basis[m]) * g[m][k] + sp.diff(Z, basis[i], basis[j]) * sp.diff(Z, basis[m]) * g[m][k]

                G[i][j][k][0] = sp.simplify(G[i][j][k][0])
               # print(G[i][j][k])

    return G


def Solve_Geodesic_Equation(u=u, v=v, G=calculate_Christoffel_Symbols()):
    solutionsl = []
    solutionsk = []
    solutionst = []
    solutions  = []
    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):
            for k in range(len(basis)):

                term = sp.diff(funcs[k], l, l) + G[i][j][k][0] * sp.diff(funcs[i], l) * sp.diff(funcs[j], l)
                term = term.subs(u, u_func)
                term = term.subs(v, v_func)

                try:
                    solution = sp.solve(term, l)
                    solutionsl.append([solution])

                    solution = sp.solve(term, k)
                    solutionsk.append([solution])

                    solution = sp.solve(term, t)
                    solutionst.append(solution)

                except(NotImplementedError):
                    pass

    for n in range(len(solutionsk)):
        if solutionsk[n] != [[]] and solutionsk[n] != []:
            solutions.append("k ={}".format(solutionsk[n]))

        if solutionsl[n] != [[]] and solutionsl[n] != []:
            solutions.append("l ={}".format(solutionsl[n]))

        if solutionst[n] != [[]] and solutionst[n] != []:
            solutions.append("t ={}".format(solutionst[n]))
    solutions = list(dict.fromkeys(solutions))
    print("Solutions : ", solutions)


def calculate_arc_length(g=compute_inverse_metric_tensor(),u=u,v=v,X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z,l=l,a=0,b=2):

    magRsqrt = 0
    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):
            if i == j:
                g[i][j] = 1 / g[i][j]
            else:
                g[i][j] = -g[i][j]

    print(g)

    for i in range(len(basis)):
        for j in range(len(basis)):

            term = sp.diff(funcs[i],l)*sp.diff(funcs[j],l) * g[i][j]
            term = term.subs(u, u_func)
            term = term.subs(v, v_func)
            term = term.subs(sp.cos(l), sp.cos(l))
            
            magRsqrt+=term
            
    
    temp = sp.simplify((magRsqrt))
    
    magR = sp.simplify(sp.sqrt(magRsqrt))
    display(magR)
    
    
    arclen = sp.Integral(magR,(l,a,b))
    
    
    display(arclen.doit())
    
    arcl = sp.Function("arcl")(l)
    eq = sp.Eq(magR,sp.Derivative(arcl,l))
    arclength = sp.dsolve(eq,arcl)
    
    display(arclength)
    
    




calculate_arc_length()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run: `line 167, in calculate_arc_length
    display(magR)
NameError: name 'display' is not defined
`

Answer (score 0):

The integral is this:

```
In [7]: l = Symbol('l')

In [8]: arclength = Integral(sqrt(exp(2*l) + sin(exp(l))**2*cos(l)**2), l)

In [9]: arclength
Out[9]: 
⌠                                
⎮    _________________________   
⎮   ╱  2⋅l      2⎛ l⎞    2       
⎮ ╲╱  ℯ    + sin ⎝ℯ ⎠⋅cos (l)  dl
⌡
```

I'm not going to dig through the rest of your code - you should shorten before posting - but you should understand that not all integrals (antiderivatives) can be computed in closed form (even in principle) and even if a closed form exists it is not guaranteed that any CAS can compute it.

However if this is supposed to be an arc-length then I would expect there to be some limits for the integral. As a definite integral with definite numeric limits it can be evaluated numerically to any desired precision:

```
In [11]: arclength = Integral(sqrt(exp(2*l) + sin(exp(l))**2*cos(l)**2), (l, 0, 1))

In [12]: arclength
Out[12]: 
1                                
⌠                                
⎮    _________________________   
⎮   ╱  2⋅l      2⎛ l⎞    2       
⎮ ╲╱  ℯ    + sin ⎝ℯ ⎠⋅cos (l)  dl
⌡                                
0                                

In [13]: arclength.n()
Out[13]: 1.91141826800283
```